# How do I know the killed process name by process ID

Tags: linux, process-management, processes

I killed a process by process ID accidentally, but now I need to know the process name.I checked the id number under folder /proc,but I got anything. how can I know the process name please.

Comment: there's no way to find it.

Comment: there may be logs, assuming the process in question was writing it's pid to a logfile somewhere somehow. probably not, though

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard mechanism in Linux to discover the `name` of a deleted process.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no map of every pid used or log of all of them any logs to journald contain a pid so if it was a daemon you can check for it with:

sudo journalctl _PID=[PID]

note that this only checks logs for the current boot.